# create civi case using standalone script

Tags: joomla, civicase

creating using standalone php script,

http://prntscr.com/n281zd

get bellow error

http://prntscr.com/n28279

Using cv cli, have same error too

> cv api Case.create case_type_id="housing_support" subject="new housing
>   object" contact_id=3

but when I pass in the CMS user I have no error and I can create the case with out any problem

> cv api Case.create case_type_id="housing_support" subject="new housing
>   object" contact_id=3 --user=admin

So the question is how to do the equivalent of --user=admin when using a php standalone script for joomla (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/bootstrap/#joomla).

Any body ever have this issues  and solve ?

Comment: Hi, Based on your other question I'm just going to edit your question to make it clearer what you're asking, if that's ok.

Comment: No problem Demerit. I have some confusion here to arrange the question. Please goon.